# .NET Razor - how to use one common checkbox for two BeginForm

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor

I need to use one checkbox that is linked with two BeginForm():

```
<div class="form-inline">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessSyncRapida", "Officine", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <button type="submit" id="syncRapida" class="btn btn-dark">Sincronizzazione Rapida</button>
    }
    
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessSyncCompleta", "Officine", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <button type="submit" id="syncCompleta" class="btn btn-dark" style="margin-left:20px">Sincronizzazione Completa</button>
    }
    > checkbox <
</div>
```

Then when a button is clicked, it should send the value of the checkbox to the server. My purpose is to avoid repetition of two checkbox that have the same meaning. Also, I'm not asking for AJAX, but if it's possible only with .NET

Comment: It's seems like you want to execute two actions by using this checkbox. If I understand this right you should change you design of this view.

Comment: If you mean you want to pass one checkbox value to backend with form post,and you don't want to put checkbox into forms,I think you can only use ajax,or put checkboxes to forms,